# Build all frameworks before running main target, Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I decided to decompose my code on separate frameworks: `UI`, `Network`, `Model`, `Utils`. I created `Cocoa Touch Framework` for each of them and added them to `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. I importing `Utils` and `UI` and the problem is that every time when I add new method/property to `Utils` – `UI` doesn't see it and to make it see I have to clean the project and rebuild every framework. I would be very grateful if someone could help me somehow automate this process. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has to do with the new build system, which doesn't build all the modules every time. You can go to `File -> Project/Workspace Settings...` and switch `Build System` to Legacy.